# FatalThrowableError in RegistrationModel.php line 11: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am getting this error in this laravel 5.3 when i declare an table as protected like this

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RegistrationModel extends Model
{
    public function savemodelstore($request)
    {
    protected $table = 'test';
    }
}
```

I don't know why i get this error? please help me

Comment: Declare your protected class variables outside of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are putting a method for just declare `protected` table. It should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RegistrationModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "test";
}
```